# Opening documents in the client application from Sharepoint Lists

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have created a couple of sharepoint lists, one that uses a lookup on the document library to link multiple documents to a list item. The other list is to create tiled links that link to documents, again in the document library.

I am using Sharepoint as part of Office 365

The problem I have is that opening the documents from these lists open in the browser instead of the client application (usually Excel), the spreadsheets are too complex for the browser based version of Excel so I need them to always open in the client application.

So far, I have set the default open option for the document library (Documents Settings > Advanced Settings) for the master site and subsite to Open in Client application by default; obviously this works for the document library, but doesn't work for the lists.

Searched for ages on this problem and either nobody has it or people that do this aren't bothered by documents opening in the browser. Would be greatful for any help on this, or if you can think of a better way to do it....

Answer (score 0):

You could export list items to excel file (`List ribbon -> Export to excel`) and then upload that excel file to some document library.
Then, the users would open the excel file from the library and they would need to refresh the data from excel, by clicking `Data ribbon -> Refresh All`

That is the closest that you can do with opening list items with excel without any programming.

Please note that users will have to be logged in to SharePoint and have the Read permissions in SharePoint list in  order to Refresh the data.

Comment: Thanks Damjan.  Looks like it's something we'll just have to suck up; I'm trying to get them away from using Excel to manage their job list, so exporting back into Excel would be counter productive.